# How do I find one number in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a file called something like FILE-1.txt or FILE-340.txt. I want to be able to get the number from the file name. I've found that I can use

```
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', '%s' %(filename))
```

to get a list containing the number, and use numbers[0] to get the number itself as a string... But if I know it is just one number, it seems roundabout and unnecessary making a list to get it. Is there another way to do this?

---

Edit: Thanks! I guess now I have another question. Rather than getting a string, how do I get the integer?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that by `'%s' %(filename)` you are converting a string to string? If `filename` is a string, then just replace `'%s' %(filename)` with `filename`.

Comment: Adding to Tadeck's comment, if `filename` is not a string then `str(filename)` is equivalent to `'%s' % filename`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `search` instead of `findall`:

```
number = re.search(r'\d+', filename).group()
```

Alternatively:

```
number = filter(str.isdigit, filename)
```

Comment: Although `filter` is more similar to `re.findall` in cases where there are multiple groups of numbers e.g. using _"FILE-340-1.txt"_ `filter` produces _"3401"_ while `re.search` only returns the first group _"340"_.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to F.J's comment, if you want an int, you can use:

```
numbers = int(re.search(r'\d+', filename).group())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your program to be effective

use this:

```
num = filename.split("-")[1][:-4]
```

this will work only to the example that you showed

Comment: It is take the second part from the splitting and than cut the last 4 chars[".txt"]

Answer (score 1):

Another way just for fun:

```
In [1]: fn = 'file-340.txt'

In [2]: ''.join(x for x in fn if x.isdigit())
Out[2]: '340'
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your new question you can cast the `string` to an `int`:

```
>>>int('123')
123
```