# Check if a string contains a number

Tags: python, string

Most of the questions I've found are biased on the fact they're looking for letters in their numbers, whereas I'm looking for numbers in what I'd like to be a numberless string.
I need to enter a string and check to see if it contains any numbers and if it does reject it.

The function `isdigit()` only returns `True` if ALL of the characters are numbers. I just want to see if the user has entered a number so a sentence like `"I own 1 dog"` or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 491, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function, with the [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function, like this

```
def has_numbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

has_numbers("I own 1 dog")
# True
has_numbers("I own no dog")
# False
```

Alternatively you can use a Regular Expression, like this

```
import re
def has_numbers(inputString):
    return bool(re.search(r'\d', inputString))

has_numbers("I own 1 dog")
# True
has_numbers("I own no dog")
# False
```

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @Ray Then the RegEx can be extended like this `r'-?\d+'`

Comment: Wouldn't the original regex detect the negative numbers anyway?

Comment: @confused00 Nope, `\d` will match only a single digit in the range `0` to `9`.

Comment: @thefourtheye: -1 is still a digit.  It is a dash, followed by the digit '1'

Comment: @thefourtheye you haven't consider if the digit at the end of string with one or more space. you will failure to detect the digit. so you may want to do it with `char.strip().isdigit()`

Comment: It would be interesting to see a timing comparison of the two methods. My gut tells me regular expressions are optimized for this kind of operation but I know better than to trust my gut.

Answer (score 81):

You can use a combination of [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
def num_there(s):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in s)
```

The function will return `True` if a digit exists in the string, otherwise `False`.

Demo:

```
>>> king = 'I shall have 3 cakes'
>>> num_there(king)
True
>>> servant = 'I do not have any cakes'
>>> num_there(servant)
False
```

Comment: No need to create a temporary list, you can use a generator expression instead just by removing those square brackets.

Comment: Ah yeah, just realized that `any` accepts generator expressions.

Answer (score 44):

Use the Python method `str.isalpha()`. This function returns True if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character; returns False otherwise.

Python Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

Comment: There are other types of characters than alphabetic and numeric - eg, `'_'.isalpha()` is False.

Comment: Chars like 'ç' and 'ñ' will not be recognized. The char 'œ' is present in Middle English texts, for instance.

Comment: The space character is also considered as none alpha using this function, which is a common character in full name for instance.

Answer (score 36):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

You should better use regular expression. It's much faster.

```
import re

def f1(string):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in string)


def f2(string):
    return re.search('\d', string)


# if you compile the regex string first, it's even faster
RE_D = re.compile('\d')
def f3(string):
    return RE_D.search(string)

# Output from iPython
# In [18]: %timeit  f1('assdfgag123')
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 µs per loop

# In [19]: %timeit  f2('assdfgag123')
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 923 ns per loop

# In [20]: %timeit  f3('assdfgag123')
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 384 ns per loop
```

Comment: f3 is not returning anything

Comment: That means there is no match, it returns `None`

Comment: RE_D = re.compile('\d')

def has_digits(string):
    res = RE_D.search(string)
    return res is not None

Comment: @Raul `f2` and `f3` return `re.Match`  objects if there is a match otherwise `None`. To get a `bool` just wrap the result `bool(re. ...)`

Answer (score 13):

You could apply the function isdigit() on every character in the String. Or you could use regular expressions.

Also I found [How do I find one number in a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234641/how-do-i-find-one-number-in-a-string-in-python) with very suitable ways to return numbers. The solution below is from the answer in that question.

```
number = re.search(r'\d+', yourString).group()
```

Alternatively:

```
number = filter(str.isdigit, yourString)
```

For further Information take a look at the regex docu: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Edit: This Returns the actual numbers, not a boolean value, so the answers above are more correct for your case

The first method will return the first digit and subsequent consecutive digits. Thus 1.56 will be returned as 1.  10,000 will be returned as 10. 0207-100-1000 will be returned as 0207.

The second method does not work.

To extract all digits, dots and commas, and not lose non-consecutive digits, use:

```
re.sub('[^\d.,]' , '', yourString)
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll make the @zyxue answer a bit more explicit:

```
import re    

RE_D = re.compile('\d')

def has_digits(string):
    res = RE_D.search(string)
    return res is not None

has_digits('asdf1')
Out: True

has_digits('asdf')
Out: False
```

which is the solution with the fastest benchmark from the solutions that @zyxue proposed on the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised that no-one mentionned this combination of `any` and `map`:

```
def contains_digit(s):
    isdigit = str.isdigit
    return any(map(isdigit,s))
```

in python 3 it's probably the fastest there (except maybe for regexes) is because it doesn't contain any loop (and aliasing the function avoids looking it up in `str`).

Don't use that in python 2 as `map` returns a `list`, which breaks `any` short-circuiting

Answer (score 4):

You can also use set.intersection
It is quite fast, better than regex for small strings.

```
def contains_number(string):
    return True if set(string).intersection('0123456789') else False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
import random
n = 10

p = ''

while (string.ascii_uppercase not in p) and (string.ascii_lowercase not in p) and (string.digits not in p):
    for _ in range(n):
        state = random.randint(0, 2)
        if state == 0:
            p = p + chr(random.randint(97, 122))
        elif state == 1:
            p = p + chr(random.randint(65, 90))
        else:
            p = p + str(random.randint(0, 9))
    break
print(p)
```

This code generates a sequence with size n which at least contain an uppercase, lowercase, and a digit. By using the while loop, we have guaranteed this event.

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Answer (score 2):

Also, you could use regex findall. It's a more general solution since it adds more control over the length of the number. It could be helpful in cases where you require a number with minimal length.

```
s = '67389kjsdk' 
contains_digit = len(re.findall('\d+', s)) > 0
```

Comment: The problem is clear and does not state it needs control over the length of the number. You are answering another question here. Please upvote or write a comment if you have suggestion for improvements.

Answer (score 2):

This too will work.

```
if any(i.isdigit() for i in s):
    print("True")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind explaining what the code does for the people who don't know? Also, a comment about your code. You should make this a function, have a test string, and instead of printing True, returning True and returning False if there are no digits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
import string

def containsNumber(line):
    res = False
    try:
        for val in line.split():
            if (float(val.strip(string.punctuation))):
                res = True
                break
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return res

containsNumber('234.12 a22') # returns True
containsNumber('234.12L a22') # returns False
containsNumber('234.12, a22') # returns True
```

Comment: Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use range with count to check how many times a number appears in the string by checking it against the range:

```
def count_digit(a):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10):
        sum += a.count(str(i))
    return sum

ans = count_digit("apple3rh5")
print(ans)

#This print 2
```

Comment: This seems very un-performant. For every character, you're looping 0-10, then linearly scanning the string, going over characters more than once... Just use `isdigit()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use NLTK method for it.

This will find both '1' and 'One' in the text:

```
import nltk 

def existence_of_numeric_data(text):
    text=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(pos)):
        word , pos_tag = pos[i]
        if pos_tag == 'CD':
            return True
    return False

existence_of_numeric_data('We are going out. Just five you and me.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this as follows:

```
if a_string.isdigit():
     do_this()
 else:
     do_that()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Using `.isdigit()` also means **not having to resort to exception handling** (try/except) in cases where you need to use list comprehension (try/except is not possible inside a list comprehension).

Comment: This checks if all characters are digits, not membership within the string

Answer (score 1):

`any` and `ord` can be combined to serve the purpose as shown below.

```
>>> def hasDigits(s):
...     return any( 48 <= ord(char) <= 57 for char in s)
...
>>> hasDigits('as1')
True
>>> hasDigits('as')
False
>>> hasDigits('as9')
True
>>> hasDigits('as_')
False
>>> hasDigits('1as')
True
>>>
```

A couple of points about this implementation.

1. `any` is better because it works like short circuit expression in C Language and will return result as soon as it can be determined i.e. in case of string 'a1bbbbbbc' 'b's and 'c's won't even be compared.
2. `ord` is better because it provides more flexibility like check numbers only between '0' and '5' or any other range. For example if you were to write a validator for Hexadecimal representation of numbers you would want string to have alphabets in the range 'A' to 'F' only.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to solve is as

```
s = '1dfss3sw235fsf7s'
count = 0
temp = list(s)
for item in temp:
    if(item.isdigit()):
        count = count + 1
    else:
        pass
print count
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
alp_num = [x for x in string.split() if x.isalnum() and re.search(r'\d',x) and 
re.search(r'[a-z]',x)]

print(alp_num)
```

This returns all the string that has both alphabets and numbers in it. isalpha() returns the string with all digits or all characters.

Answer (score -1):

An iterator approach. It consumes all characters unless a digit is met. The second argument of `next` fix the default value to return when the iterator is "empty". In this case it set to `False` but also `''` works since it is casted to a boolean value in the `if`.

```
def has_digit(string):
    str_iter = iter(string)
    while True:
        char = next(str_iter, False)
        # check if iterator is empty
        if char:
            if char.isdigit():
                return True
        else:
            return False
```

or by looking only at the 1st term of a generator comprehension

```
def has_digit(string):
    return next((True for char in string if char.isdigit()), False)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised nobody has used the python operator `in`. Using this would work as follows:

```
foo = '1dfss3sw235fsf7s'
bar = 'lorem ipsum sit dolor amet'

def contains_number(string):
    for i in range(10):
        if str(i) in list(string):
            return True
    return False

print(contains_number(foo)) #True
print(contains_number(bar)) #False
```

Or we could use the function `isdigit()`:

```
foo = '1dfss3sw235fsf7s'
bar = 'lorem ipsum sit dolor amet'

def contains_number(string):
    for i in list(string):
        if i.isdigit():
            return True
    return False

print(contains_number(foo)) #True
print(contains_number(bar)) #False
```

These functions basically just convert `s` into a list, and check whether the list contains a digit. If it does, it returns `True`, if not, it returns `False`.