# Not making integer inputs

Tags: python, input, integer

I want a way for the user not to make an integer input by using this function:

```
x = input("Whats your name?") 
while x == int:
y = input("why is there a number in your name? Please re enter your name")
```

But this does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: use `isinstance(x, int)` instead of x==int ?

Comment: the language is python

Comment: this does not work I still enter an integer and the shell accepts it

Comment: I know it's probably just a learning exercise, but for the future I wanted to refer you to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) - specifically "15. People’s names do not contain numbers."

Answer (score 2):

Improving in @persian_dev's answer -

```
def check_name(string):
    for char in string :
        try:
            int(char)
            return False
        except:
            continue
    return True
```

This will traverse the string, try to convert each character to int and return False on first success in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The input function will convert anything user enters to a string.

So you want to instead look whether there is any number contained in x, rather than the type.

See here:
[check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

here is a check function :

```
def isnumeric(string):
    try:
        int(string)
        return True
    except:
    return False

def check_name(string):
    for char in string:
        if isnumeric(char):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: The call to `isnumeric` from `check_name` for each character might be slow for performance. We can instead try the conversiotn of char to int in `check_name` itself.

Comment: thanks thats a good point ...

Comment: And I guess you meant `string` instead of `str` in that for loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make sure the user input contains strings only, you can use `isalpha()` to check the input:

```
x = raw_input("Whats your name?") 
while not x.isalpha():
    x = raw_input("why is there a number in your name? Please re enter your name")
```

*I use Python 2 so I used `raw_input` instead of `input`. If you use Python 3 you can adjust accordingly.*

Answer (score -1):

`int` is a type. You're not asking *"Does x contain a number?"* or even *"Is x a number?"*, you're asking *"Is x number?"* (integer, more precisely). Makes no sense. Assuming entering names work, you're using Python 3, in which case the result of `input` is always a string. Even if it's a string of only digits. So `isinstance(x, int)` won't work, either. You could try casting with `int(...)`, but that won't help if the name contains a number only somewhere among letters.

Here's a good way to test whether there's any digit in a string:

> any(map(str.isdigit, x))

In your code, also with the `y` corrected to `x`:

```
x = input("Whats your name? ")
while any(map(str.isdigit, x)):
    x = input("why is there a number in your name? Please re enter your name ")
```