# Remove all items in Python list containing a number

Tags: python, list

What is an optimal way of removing all items containing a number from a large list of strings?

**Input:**  ['This', 'That', 'Those4423', '42', '13b' 'Yes', '2']

**Output:**  ['This', 'That', 'Yes']

Comment: An optimal way probably means you have suboptimal ones?

Comment: You can basically apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number solution in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> foo = ['This', 'That', 'Those4423', '42', '13b', 'Yes', '2']
>>> foo1 = [x for x in foo if not any(x1.isdigit() for x1 in x)]
>>> foo
['This', 'That', 'Those4423', '42', '13b', 'Yes', '2']
>>> foo1
['This', 'That', 'Yes']
>>>
```

However you can use `.isalpha()` to check if the string contains alphabetic characters only.

```
.isaplha()
 [x for x in foo if x.isalpha()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
[element for element in my_list if all(digit not in element for digit in "1234567890")]
```