# How to check if an input is a valid name in python

Tags: python, string, input, spaces, isalpha

I tried this code:

```
name = str(input("What is your name? "))
if not name.isalpha():
        print("Please enter a valid name.")
        continue
```

but when I enter a name with a space or full name, I get the "Please enter a valid name." statement even if I only entered a name without any other types of data i.e. int, float.

Does the space count as a string?
If not, how should I change my code so that it will accept a full name with spaces but not accept numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: Use regular expresions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number

Comment: use if name.replace(" ","").isalpha():

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to check if each character is either a space or a letter. You can do that manually by going through each letter.

```
name = str(input("What is your name? "))
if not all(x.isalpha or x == "" for x in  name):
    print("Please enter a valid name.")
else:
    print(name)
```

Comment: I do not only want to check if each character is a space or letter. I want to check it if it has no number but a valid name, possibly containing space as I will use the data later in a program.

Comment: @BjCuizon. You need to specify exactly what you mean by a valid name. Without that information, your question is not answerable.