# check a string is true for two functions in python (string manipulation)

Tags: python, string, function, conditional-statements

I have the following code and while it works for just checking one function (say the lower case), it stops working when two conditions are introduced. Could someone shed some light for teaching purposes, on why this is the case, give a solution, and explain the rationale. Note: this is not a duplicate of any other question, as the other examples don't explicitly deal with string boolean commands.

**Expected outcome**: The email address should only be generated IF the username input is lowercase AND contains digits. (e.g. username123 is acceptable, USER is not, USER123 is not)

The **solution/answer** must be simple and ideally not include a rewrite of the code (i.e without rewriting the function and introducing parameters etc, if this as possible)

**Code:**

```
def main():
   print("*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************")
   print("***************************                                               ********************** ")

   username=input("Please enter your desired username:" )

   if username.islower() and username.isdigit():
         email=username+"@gmail.com"
         print("Your unique email address is now:", email)
   else:
         print("Your username needs to be lower case ...............")
         main()

main()
```

As mentioned, the below code (checking for just the islower) works ....

```
   if username.islower():
         email=username+"@gmail.com"
         print("Your unique email address is now:", email)
   else:
         print("Your username needs to be lower case ...............")
         main()
```

**Working output:**

```
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:USER
Your username needs to be lower case ...............
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:user
Your unique email address is now: user@gmail.com
>>>
```

**UPDATE:**
Someone suggested it was due to the missing (), but this isn't the case:

```
def main():
   print("*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************")
   print("***************************                                               ********************** ")

   username=input("Please enter your desired username:" )
   if username.islower() and username.isdigit():
         email=username+"@gmail.com"
         print("Your unique email address is now:", email)
   else:
         print("Your username needs to be lower case ...............")
         main()
main()
```

**Erroneous output:**

```
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:USER
Your username needs to be lower case ...............
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:user
Your username needs to be lower case ...............
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:user123
Your username needs to be lower case ...............
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:
```

**Removing the recursive main() call doesn't change things either:**

```
def main():
   print("*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************")
   print("***************************                                               ********************** ")
   username=input("Please enter your desired username:" )
   if username.islower() and username.isdigit():
         email=username+"@gmail.com"
         print("Your unique email address is now:", email)
   else:
         print("Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............")
main()
```

**Erroneous output:**

```
Please enter your desired username:USERNAME
Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............
>>> main()
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:username123
Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............
>>>
```

**Using OR instead of AND does not work either**

Output below, when changed to OR

```
Please enter your desired username:USERNAME
Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............
>>> main()
*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
***************************                                               ********************** 
Please enter your desired username:username
Your unique email address is now: username@gmail.com
>>>
```

Trying another suggested answer below using set(range(10)).intersection:

**The following - still not working:**

```
def main():
   print("*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************")
   print("***************************                                               ********************** ")
   username=input("Please enter your desired username:" )
   #if username.islower() or username.isdigit():
   if username.islower() and set(range(10)).intersection(username):
         email=username+"@gmail.com"
         print("Your unique email address is now:", email)
   else:
         print("Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............")
main()
```

**Output**

```
  >>> main()
    *************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
    ***************************                                               ********************** 
    Please enter your desired username:user
    Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............
    >>> main()
    *************************** Create an e-mail address*********************
    ***************************                                               ********************** 
    Please enter your desired username:username123
    Your username needs to be lower case and contain digits...............
    >>>
```

Comment: you forgot the parentheses for the islower() function call in the first example.

Comment: Sorry, I've added that in the code. That is in the original code - and does not work. Do run it and see -!

Comment: Your first code snippet is recursive; you call `main()` in `main()`

Comment: Chris, yes, but removing that doesn't solve the problem (see update)

Comment: 'and username.isdigit()' ... 'user' is false for this. did you mean 'and not username.isdigit()' and requires both sides to evaluate to True

Comment: @pythoncarrot you are checking `islower() and isdigit()`. Digits are not lowercase and letters are not digits, so its always false. I assume you either mean `or` (name is lower case or purely numbers) or `and not` (lowercase and not purely numbers) or something similar.

Comment: I want the username to be validated: the user should only input a lowercase entry WITH numbers. so the email should only be generated IF the username is BOTH lowercase AND has digits ...?

Comment: @pythoncarrot then you don't want "isdigits()", but you want some function that checks if the username CONTAINS digits, which you may have to write yourself.

Comment: @pythoncarrot please update question to contain valid and invalid names, it makes the answering alot simpler.

Comment: see update - has been done. valid: username123 invalid: USERNAME invalid: username. And I wish someone would upvote my q rather than whoever downvoted it (why?!) ....makes life hard for a newbie like me to build up a reputation!

Comment: Is username *a1b2c3* valid? Or should both letter and digit sets be consequent, such as in your examples?

Comment: Nevermind, I have added a possible solution for both cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple function

```
def hasNumbers(inputString):
      return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
.
.
.
if username.islower() and hasNumbers(username):
.
.
.
```

and then use it in the if statement. This is the source I found it from: [check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number) .
You can also use regex if you prefer that, using the re module. But for something as small as this, I would recommend you go with a separate function. Its a more...simpler solution.

Regex version:

```
import re

def main():
   print("*************************** Create an e-mail address*********************")
   print("***************************                                               ********************** ")

   username=str(input("Please enter your desired username:" ))

   pat = re.compile(r'\d')

   if username.islower() and re.search(pat, username):
         email=username+"@gmail.com"
         print("Your unique email address is now:", email)
   else:
         print("Your username needs to be lower case ...............")
         main()

main()
```

Comment: changing it to "or" instead of "and" does not work either. See edit with output

Comment: depends if the OP is intending to allow numeric usernames: if not intending numbers as username then the 2nd part requires a not operator.

Comment: I agree. I am trying to find out what he really wants as output.

Comment: Oh I get it now. He wants the username to contain lowercase alphabets and digits

Comment: From this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number
Use the function
`def hasNumbers(inputString):
                  return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)`
and use the function passing your string as the argument. Then all you need to do is, change the error message.
Sorry, *she

Comment: isdigit() is not the right function to use for a string. it works only on a character.

Comment: @pythoncarrot I think I have got it. Shall i edit the answer?

Comment: surely there is a way then to see if a STRING contains a list of digits (0 to 9) and include it simply in the if statement above? Is reg ex the only way to go....

Comment: Regex is quite easy using the re module. I don't think you can simplify it more than that. :)

Comment: Are you able to add an answer using regex within the if

Comment: @pythoncarrot Please do tick this as answer if it worked out :) So that it helps the others in the SO community as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this line

`if username.islower() and username.isdigit()`

is that `isdigit()` returns True only if the entire string is numbers and `islower()` will obviously only return True if the entire string is lower case characters. This means that this statement will always fail as both conditions cannot be true.

If we rethink the logic a bit what we need to test is that the email only contains alphanumeric characters (numbers and letters) but does not contain any upper case letters. This gives us:

`if username.isalnum() and (not any(c.isupper() for c in username)`

Answer (score 1):

It has been stated that the problem with your code is if you execute `username.isdigit()` it returns `False` statement because the variable **username** is not completely filled with digits, though, `islower()` is not as strict:

```
username = input(' -->> ')
-->> abc123

username.isdigit()
```

> False

```
username.islower()
```

> True

In your specific case, you may omit warnings if there are uppercase letters as you may transform them into lowercase. **If you need a solution where there is also a check for uppercase letters, then you should also read the additional section in the end**.

If the structure of **username** does not really bother you, i.e. you simply want it to contain both lowercase letters and digits, then you may simply check if they both exist using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re  # regular expressions

username = 'Abc123'  # similar to input() as it also returns 'str' class

if re.match('^[a-z0-9]*$', username.lower()):  # username.lower() makes letters lowercase. You could assign it to a new variable if needed.
    email = username.lower() + '@gmail.com'
    print('Your e-mail address is: {}'.format(email))
```

It works well even if `username = 'A1b2C3'`, for instance.

---

However, if the structure is important and you want digits follow letters at any cost, you should divide the **username** into two subsets, one containing letters and other containing digits and check if both exist in the correct order. **Note that it is just a personal approach**:

- Firstly, we check **username** if we can successively divide it into two sets of letters and digits, not more and not less;
- Secondly, we check if the first subset contains letters and the second subset contains digits;
- If the conditions are satisfied, then we create an e-mail.

The code should be the following:

```
import re

print('Example of username: george1337')
username = 'Abc123'; username = username.lower()

if len(re.findall('\d+|\D+', username)) == 2:
    subset_1, subset_2 = [subset for subset in re.findall('\d+|\D+', username)]
else:
    print('Not valid username: see example')

if subset_1.islower() and subset_2.isdigit():
    email = username + '@gmail.com'
    print('Your e-mail address is: {}'.format(email))
else:
    print('Digits must follow letters, not vice versa')
```

> Your e-mail address is: abc123@gmail.com

```
username = 'a2BB3dd4'; username = username.lower()

if len(re.findall('\d+|\D+', username)) == 2:
    subset_1, subset_2 = [subset for subset in re.findall('\d+|\D+', username)]
else:
    print('Not valid username: see example')
```

> Not valid username: see example

---

### Additional section

Okay. If you wish to raise a warning if there are uppercase letters, then you should not execute `username = username.lower()`. The 'uppercase condition' will be automatically checked in the second section as there is `if subset_1.islower()`. You should then simply add another `print` indicating that uppercase letters are not allowed. The same goes with the first section.

I hope that helps!