# simplest way to check if there is any number in a string and if so to output what i want

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and i would like to know how to find if there is a numeric value in a string, and if so, to output what i choose. I have tried Regex but it does not let me choose my own Output.

Comment: What are you trying to output?

Comment: Have you check this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number