# Python regex to find digit in first n characters

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering if it is possible to use a regex to check the first n characters of a string and determine if any of them contain a digit?

I realize this can be done by first splitting the string and then using a \d on the substring, but I would like to see a solution where it could be done in one shot

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it with regex and also, without regex. Refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19859282/4410922). But SO is not here to provide you solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it in 1 shot, but not the way you'd expect:

```
r'\D{n}'
```

That is, it matches string of length n that does *not* contain any digits; thus, if the match fails, there must be a digit in the first n characters.

Comment: Yep, works as expected. Good to know, thanks!