# How to learn is there a numbers in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers, int

I have a task to make a function that returns True if there's a number (0-9) in word and False if there's no number in word:

```
def has_digits(string):
    for r in range (0,10)
    if r in string:
        return 'True'
    else: return 'False'

print(has_digits('Python3'))
```

Generally I have this error message:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Comment: Well given that you have `for r in range(0, 10):`, inside the loop `r` will be an `int`. When you do `if r in string:`, therefore, you're going to try to evaluate e.g. `0 in 'Python3'` and, as the error tells you, that doesn't make sense. Also your indentation is broken as posted and they probably want you to return the booleans `True` and `False` not a string that just looks like it.

Comment: this is nicer: `return any(char.isdigit() for char in string)` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `int` object from your `for` loop to a `str` object because `if a in b` only works for `a` and `b` as an string (`str`) object. And you have to remove one `return` from the loop. Otherwise the method `isDigit` will end with `true` or `false` at the first letter of your string.

```
def has_digits(string):
    for r in range(0, 10):
        if str(r) in string:
            return true

    return false

print(has_digits("Python3"))

>> true
```

Now the method will return `true` if your string contains a digit. Otherwise it will loop further through the string and check the next letters. At the end the method returns `false` because the string ends and the method doesn´t return with `true` from the loop.

How does this code works now?
Assume that you pass the string `Python3` into the method `has_digits` then the first `for` loop iterate over the numbers `0` to `9`. So during the first loop `r` is equal `0`. Now the conditional check `if str(r) in string` will occur. The `if` statement checks if `str(0)` (`"0"` the string version of the number `0`) is in the string `string` (which is your `Python3`). There is no `"0"` in it, so the condition is `false` and the `for` loop continues with `1`. The whole procedure repeat until `3`. For `3` the `if` statement returns `true`, because `"3"` is in `Python3` and now the method will return `true` which signal that your string has **at least** one digit.

Comment: This is a quite interesting case. Okay so with str(r) i made thouse "numbers" string format rithg? 
So the position of the "return 'False" does the thing.

I don't quite get the logic of how it works

Comment: Yes. `str(a)` convert the object `a` into a `string` object. Now you have all methods for a `string` object available (like the `if(a in b)` check). I will update my answer to explain the logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
def has_digits(string):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in string)

print(has_digits('abc1'))
```

Your example should be like this to work:

```
def has_digits(string):
    b = False
    for r in range(0, 10):
        if str(r) in string:
            b = True
    return b


print(has_digits('Python3'))
```

You should have parsed `str(r)` and secondly your function would check if `0` is in your string and return `false` immediately. Would not run for the rest values in your loop.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service, and this doesn't explain to the OP why their initial attempt didn't work.

Comment: What actually char.isdigit does? And why it doesn't have any varible inside?

Comment: @Balloonbear that information is available in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: @Balloonbear `char.isdigit()` checks if a character is a number and that runs for every single character in your string. Your example didn't work first of all because you should have parsed `str(r) and secondly your function would check if 0 is in your string and return immediately. Would not run for the rest. I fixed your example too to work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is that better? I gave him a working example. I didn't that I had to explain the wrong one too.

Comment: It still doesn't explain what the problem was. The solution is trivial, yes, but if they just copy-paste it what have they learned (other than that they can just dump their next trivial problem here, too)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I explained in a comment above. Wasn't that sufficient?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, useful information should be *in your post*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok then.

Comment: One should keep in mind .isdigit() expected behaviour with superscript and subscript: '₄₂'.isdigit()  is True. It depends on context whether these should be considered digits or not. Trying to convert these digits into integer with int() will raise ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if r in string:
```

to this:

```
if str(r) in string:
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a mistake in your code.

```py
def has_digits(string):
    for r in range (0,10)  # here; should have a :(colon) at the end
    if r in string:
        return 'True'
    else: return 'False'

print(has_digits('Python3'))
```

Correct code should be:

```py
def has_digits(string):
    for r in range(10):
        r = str(r)
        if r in string:
            return True
    return False

print(has_digits('Python3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the error is you are checking for integer value in string. So change

> if r in string

to

> if str(r) in string

Also there is no need for else inside the loop as it will return the false if the first character is not a digit so you will not get correct answer, you can change it to something like

```
def has_digits(string):
    for r in range (0,10):
         if str(r) in string:
             return 'True' # use boolean return for better use
    return false
```

Though this is correct way and you will get your results but learn about list comprehensions and generators. You will get your results quicker and in better way.

Answer (score -1):

This error arise because you are comparing string with int. 
change `r in string` to `str(r) in string` will resolve this error.

```
def has_digits(string):
    for r in range (0,10):
        if str(r) in string:
            return 'True'    
    return 'False'

print(has_digits('Python3'))
```