# How to check if value/character in a string is equal to an integer. Python

Tags: python

I am trying to check if in a string(eg "Hello my name is 3") if there is a number. In my example the code I want to write would identify the number 3.

I have tried the code bellow. 
I know the "int(range(1,10)): " part is not going to work at all but I put it there to show what im trying to achieve if that makes sense.

```
for x in text:
    if x != " " or x != int(range(1,10)):
        print(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

To test if string contains a number:

```
>>> def hasNumbers(inputString):
...     return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

>>> hasNumbers("Hello my name is 3")
True
>>> hasNumbers("Hello my name is p")
False
```

To extract number:

```
>>> int(filter(str.isdigit, inputString))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, you just need another for loop after the first.

```py
for i in range(1,10): #this will only check 1-9
    if i != int(x):
        print(x)
```

Alternatively, you could use regular expressions, which would be faster with a larger range of numbers;

```py
import re
if not re.match("[0-9]",x):
    print(x)
```

This checks for a digit 0-9 in x, and prints if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just test that your string has a proper decimal, try this

```
test='Hello my name is 3'
if any((x.isdecimal() for x in test.split())):
   # Yes
```

Note: This won' work for example, `Hello my name is3`

If you want to check digit-by-digit, then just remove the split.

```
any((x.isdecimal() for x in test))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Use regular expression library: `regex`

```py
import re
s = "Hello my name is 3"

re.findall("\d*", s)
```

#### Output

```
3
```