# A way to check if string includes both string and digit at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

I'm trying to find the word that includes strings and numbers both at the same time. I tried to do something like:

```
string = "bear666 got sentenced 70 years in prison"

values = string.split()

for i in values:
    if i.isalpha() and i.isdigit():
        print(i)
```

but nothing worked. Help would be much appreciated

I'm trying to get beaar666 as an output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Comment: A guy below just wrote almost same thing, thank you for the help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
string = "bear666 got sentenced 70 years in prison"
words = string.split(" ")

def hasNumbersAndAlphabets(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString) and any(c.isalpha() for c in inputString)

for word in words :
    if hasNumbersAndAlphabets(word) :
        print(word)
```

Comment: You can do it in one comparison like this: `any(char.isdigit() and char.isalpha() for char in inputString)` that way it's faster.

Comment: @Marcos You can't. How can a character be both digit and alphabet at the same time?

Comment: Oh, my bad, that's `True`, I read what the op wrote. It can't be! @GaganTK

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
import re
string = "bear666 got sentenced 70 years in prison 666dog"
re.findall(r'(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+)', string)
```

Output:

```
['bear666', '666dog']
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: This doesn't work if a word has number first and letter next

Answer (score 2):

`isalpha()` and `isdigit()` check wether the entire word is only made from digits (or only from letters respectively).

you check both by iterating over all letters of a word, like this:

```py
string = "bear666 got sentenced 70 years in prison"

values = string.split()

for i in values:
    if any(char.isalpha() for char in i) and any(char.isdigit() for char in i):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Yeah, now I understand. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `re.search()` *twice.*  The first pattern searches for letters; the second searches for digits.  `if` *both* patterns match, the string contains both letters and digits.

Comment: Well, I'm new to python and don't know how the functions from libraries work so currently I prefer to write codes without them,