# How do you ask if there is a number in your string?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to ask for someone's name but I'm not sure how to tell if there is a number in there answer.
code:

```
 name1ask = ("wrong")
 while name1ask != ("right"):
   name1 = input("What's player 1's name?") 
   spaces = " " in name1
   if type(name1) != str : #here I try to check if its a number(integer)
      print("Words only") 
   elif len(name1) > 10:
      print("Names under 10 letters only")
   elif spaces == True:
      print("No spaces")
   else:
      print("Welcome " + name1)
      name1ask = ("right")
```

Comment: Kindly share the code you've tried so we can help you correct it.

Comment: Suppose there is a number in the answer: why do you care?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `any` check in your `while` loop to check if any of your letters in name is a digit and repeat the input if so:

```
name1 = '1'
while any(x.isdigit() for x in name1):
    name1 = input("What's player 1's name? ")
```

---

In your case, you can replace these lines of code:

```
if type(name1) != str : # here I try to check if its a number(integer)
    print("Words only")
```

with:

```
if any(x.isdigit() for x in name1):
    print("Words only")
```

Comment: Follow up question, how would I check for symbols? Thanks for your previous answer

Comment: That almost changed wholly from your question title and any answer I provide further will deviate further readers unless you modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the string name contains a number

```py
any([str(element) in name for element in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]])
```