# Presence of a number in a string with regural expression in python

Tags: python, regex

If I would determine if there is a presence of a number in a string what re I need to use?
With this I have some issue:

```
string_var = "122 aaaa bbb 222"

re.search("^[0-9]$",string_var)
```

Thanks,

Comment: This checks if the *entire* input is just numbers. Remove the `^` and `$` characters to check for any position.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861306/3832970, `\d ` is enough to check for a digit. `\d+` will extract whole chunks of digits if used with `re.findall`.