# Check whether a String value contains a numeric figure using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, alphanumeric

I am looking for a very particular function using python which when given a variable, it will determine whether that variable contains any number from 0-9, therefore I do not want to determine if a variable is purely numeric, I simply want to determine whether numbers exist within the String containing other characters.

For example, the variable 'CTF3WE' would be flagged, since there is a number 3. Does a function to serve such a problem exist? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Comment: @mulaixi yes, I somehow did not come across it before posting. Thanks