# check if string contains an integer python

Tags: python, numbers

I need to check if a character entered in a password contains an integer or not.

```
password = input("Enter a password:" )
for num in password:
    if num.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        print("Your password must contain a number.")
```

The code above doesn't work because I'm assuming due to python 3 taking every user input as a string, it checks the string and never knows the difference between the string and the integer in the string. How would I get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Comment: No, your logic is just wrong.

Comment: You give up checking and proclaim it must contain a number right on the first character. Remove the `else` and print/handle failure only after the entire loop is done, meaning you checked each character and none were digits (the `break` should probably set some sort of variable first). Simpler: `any(x.isdigit() for x in password)`

Comment: you may want to use a while loop

Comment: Or did you intend  the `else` belong to the `for` instead of the `if`? That would actually be correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've realised it's a silly indentation error and just completely overlooked it. Yes I did intend for that @mkrieger1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine if you unindent the `else` to make it part of the `for`:

```
for num in password:
    if num.isdigit():
        break
else:
    print("Your password must contain a number.")
```

If it's part of the `if`, the `else` happens for every character that's not a digit; if it's part of the `for`, it happens at the end of the loop *if the loop was never broken*, which is the behavior you want.

An easier way of writing the same check is with the `any` function ("if there aren't any digits..."):

```
if not any(num.isdigit() for num in password):
    print("Your password must contain a number.")
```

or equivalently with `all` ("if all the characters aren't digits..."):

```
if all(not num.isdigit() for num in password):
    print("Your password must contain a number.")
```

Comment: Thank you, silly mistake. I may adopt the any function method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will print `Your password must contain a number.` for every non-digit character. You need to know if there is a digit in the password or not, then make decision about its validity. So you can use a boolean variable, then if any digit character found in the password, the variable would be `True` and after `for` loop you will use it for checking the validity of password.

You can do like this:

```
password = input("Enter a password:" )
good_pass = False

for num in password:
    if num.isdigit():
        good_pass = True
        break

if good_pass == True:
    print('Good password!')
else:
    print("Your password must contain a number.")
```

Comment: thanks, solved it. Didn't realise my error.