# count, print out and delete rows that do not contain a digit

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Please see the following minimal reproducible example.

```
{'URL': {68020: 'URL', 68021: 'https://www.funda.nl/koop/verkocht/vlijmen/huis-42544400-oranjelaan-55/'}, 'OfferedSince': {68020: 'OfferedSince', 68021: '20 december 2021'}, 'DateOfSale': {68020: 'DateOfSale', 68021: '22 december 2021'}, 'AskingPrice': {68020: 'AsingPrice', 68021: '269000 '}, 'Description': {68020: 'Description', 68021: 'Interessante royale woning, uitgebouwd op de begane grond, deels verbouwd en gemoderniseerd. Voorzien van een riante woonkamer met airconditioning, moderne halfopen keuken met inbouwapparatuur. De woning heeft in 2021 een nieuw dak gekregen en is voorzien van een twaalftal zonnepanelen. Op een aantal punten dient de woning nog te worden aangepast/afgerond maar dat is grotendeels al gereed. Centrale ligging nabij alle benodigde faciliteiten zoals winkels, scholen, busverbinding en goede aansluiting met de A59 waardoor steden als ’s-Hertogenbosch, Waalwijk en Tilburg goed bereikbaar zijn. Tevens liggen de Loonse- en Drunense Duinen en vestingstad Heusden op een steenworp afstand. Indeling Begane grond Entree/Hal Entree aan de voorzijde van de woning. Je komt binnen in de hal welke is voorzien van de meterkast (groepenkast 2021, glasvezel, aansluiting voor inductie koken aanwezig), de omvormer van de 12 zonnepanelen, toegang naar de multifunctionele ruimte met bijkeuken en de trapopgang naar de eerste verdieping. Multifunctionele ruimte / bijkeuken. Van oorsprong is de woning van het type drive-in, dat wil zeggen dat er oorspronkelijk een garage op de begane grond is gelegen. In de loop van de jaren is er een pui geplaatst op de plek van de garagedeur waardoor er nu een multifunctionele ruimte is ontstaan. Ideaal voor kantoor aan huis. Er is op de begane grond een extra toilet geplaatst. In de multifunctionele ruimte is de van oorsprong gelegen smeerput nog gelegen, deze is momenteel dichtgezet. Aan de achterzijde is de opstelplaats van wasmachine en droger. De multifunctionele ruimte is niet volledig afgebouwd en behoeft nog de nodige werkzaamheden om het af te ronden. Separaat is de bijkeuken gelegen met een volledig keukenblok voorzien van wasbak en gaskookplaat. In de tussenruimte is een extra kast voorzien van koel-vriescombinatie. Op deze verdieping is tevens de CV ketel geplaatst (Intergas 2012). Dit betreft een CV ketel die geleased is inclusief onderhoudscontract. Vanuit de multifunctionele ruimte bereik je de achtertuin. Eerste verdieping Via de trap bereik je de eerste verdieping en kom je op de overloop waar zich het toilet en een extra kast bevinden. Hier is te trap naar de tweede verdieping en de toegang naar de woonkamer. Woonkamer en keuken Bij binnenkomst in de woonkamer valt meteen de hoeveelheid lichtinval op. Het is een ruime en erg lichte ruimte. Voorzien van een fraaie massief houtenvloer. Aan de achterzijde is de eetruimte welke aaneengesloten is aan de ruime keuken. Hier is de airconditioning geplaatst welke de volledige verdieping in warme dagen koel houdt. De keuken is voorzien van een combi-stoomoven, koel-vriescombinatie, een 4-pits gaskookplaat en RVS afzuigkap, vaatwasser en spoelbak. Tevens is er veel kast- en opbergruimte. Het bouwjaar van de keuken dateert van 2012. In de keuken is een tegelvloer gelegen. Tweede verdieping Via een vaste trap is de tweede verdieping bereikbaar. Hier bevinden zich 3 slaapkamers en de badkamer. De eerste slaapkamer is aan de voorzijde gelegen. Deze kamer is voorzien van een airconditioning en een fraaie laminaatvloer. Slaapkamer twee ligt aan de achterzijde en is nog af te ronden, de huidige eigenaren hebben deze kamer momenteel niet in gebruik. De derde slaapkamer is ook aan de achterzijde gelegen en is, net als de overloop en eerste slaapkamer, voorzien van een fraaie laminaatvloer. Op de overloop komt daglicht via de lichtkoepel. Het plafond dient nog afgerond te worden. Het plattedak van het hoofdgebouw dateert van 2021 evenals de 12 zonnepanelen. Badkamer De badkamer is modern en deels betegeld, deels gestuukt en voorzien van een inloopdouche met glazen wanden, een wandcloset en een wastafel. Exterieur Achtertuin Vanuit de multifunctionele ruimte is de achtertuin bereikbaar. De tuin is ruim van opzet en dient nog aangelegd te worden. Oprit Aan de voorzijde van de woning is een oprit waar 2 auto’s geparkeerd kunnen worden aanwezig. Bijzonderheden * Volledig nieuw dak op het hoofdhuis (2021) voorzien van 12 zonnepanelen (2021) * Mooie riante moderne woonkeuken (2012) * Ruime en lichte woonkamer * 3 slaapkamers en moderne badkamer * Oprit voor 2 auto’s * Multifunctionele ruimte op de begane grond * Mooie ligging tegenover een speelparkje * De woning dient op een aantal punten nog afgebouwd/afgerond te worden'}, 'Postcode': {68020: 'Postcode', 68021: '5251 JK'}, 'LivingArea': {68020: 'LivingArea', 68021: '158 '}, 'PlotArea': {68020: 'PlotArea', 68021: '196 '}, 'Rooms': {68020: 'Rooms', 68021: '6'}, 'Bedrooms': {68020: 'Bedrooms', 68021: '3'}, 'Bathrooms': {68020: 'Bathrooms', 68021: '1'}, 'EnergyLabel': {68020: 'EnergyLabel', 68021: 'A'}, 'BuildYear': {68020: 'BuildYear', 68021: '1969'}, 'TypeOfHouse': {68020: 'TypeOfHouse', 68021: 'Eengezinswoning, tussenwoning (drive-in woning)'}, 'Garden': {68020: 'Garden', 68021: 'Achtertuin en voortuin'}, 'Garden-yes-no': {68020: 'Garden-yes-no', 68021: 'Yes'}}
```

I would like to print out all the rows that do not contain a digit in the 'AskingPrice' column.

In the above reproducible example, this would be the row 68020. What is the most efficient way to select a row that does not contain a digit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.pd.DataFrame(dict_you_provided)

print(df[df["AskingPrice"].astype(str).str.contains(pat="[a-zA-Z]", regex=True)])

# Output
       URL  OfferedSince  DateOfSale AskingPrice  ...  BuildYear  TypeOfHouse  Garden  Garden-yes-no
68020  URL  OfferedSince  DateOfSale  AsingPrice  ...  BuildYear  TypeOfHouse  Garden  Garden-yes-no
```