# Efficiently check if string contains a digit in python

Tags: python, string

I have a huge amount (GB) of text to process, sentence by sentence.
In each sentence I have a costly operation to perform on numbers, so I check that this sentence contains at least one digit.
I have done this check using different means and measured those solutions using `timeit`.

`s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' # example`

- `any(c.isdigit() for c in s)`  3.61 µs
- `re.search('\d', s)`  402 ns
- `d = re.compile('\d')` `d.search(s)` 126 ns
- `'0' in s or '1' in s or '2' in s or '3' in s or '4' in s or '5' in s or '6' in s or '7' in s or '8' in s or '9' in s`  60ns

The last way is the fastest one, but it is ugly and probably 10x slower than possible.

Of course I could rewrite this in cython, but it seems overkill.

Is there a better pure python solution? In particular, I wonder why you can use `str.startswith()` and `str.endswith()` with a tuple argument, but it does not seem to be possible with `in` operator.

Comment: Try `any(d in s for d in '0123456789')` it should be equivalent to the last option but reads better

Comment: Have you tried regex with reusing a compiled regular expression (`pattern = re.compile(r'\d')`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number)

Comment: @rdas, true more readable, but 304 ns

Comment: @0x263A
  it is my way 1

Comment: @Oli better than non-compiled, but still not as fast as last way. Reviewed this solution in my post

Comment: There's yet another way to go about it, I don't think it's the most efficient though: `tbl = ''.maketrans('', '', '0123456789'); txt != txt.translate(tbl)`

Comment: @Peter, nice idea, but 178 ns

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the "costly operation"?

Comment: @0x263A regex sub for processing numbers written using various local number formats (decimal point, thousand sep, ...), and that may be sticked or not with units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual performance might vary depending on your platform and python version, but on my setup (python 3.9.5 / Ubuntu), it turns out that `re.match` is significantly faster than `re.search`, and outperforms the long `in` series version. Also, compiling the regex with `[0-9]` instead of `\d` provides a little improvement.

```py
import re
from timeit import timeit

n = 10_000_000
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

# reference
timeit(lambda: '0' in s or '1' in s or '2' in s or '3' in s or '4' in s or '5' in s or '6' in s or '7' in s or '8' in s or '9' in s, number=n)
# 2.1005349759998353

# re.search with \d, slower
re.compile('\d')
timeit(lambda: d.search(s), number=n)
# 2.9816031390000717

# re.search with [0-9], better but still slower then reference
d = re.compile('[0-9]')
timeit(lambda: d.search(s), number=n)
# 2.640713582999524

# re.match with [0-9], faster than reference
d = re.compile('[0-9]')
timeit(lambda: d.match(s), number=n)
# 1.5671786130005785
```

So, *on my machine*, using `re.match` with a compiled `[0-9]` pattern is about 25% faster than the long `or ... in` chaining. And it looks better too.

Comment: Interesting. On my machine, re.compile() + match() is also faster than ref solution. Good job !