# Better way to check if variable is string of integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if some variable is an integer within quotes. So, naturally, I did the following:

```
! pip install smartprint 

def isIntStr(n):
    # first, the item must be a string 
    if not isinstance(n, str):
        return False

    # second, we try to convert it to integer
    try:
        int(n)
        return True
    except:
        return False


from smartprint import smartprint as sprint 

sprint (isIntStr("123_dummy"))
sprint (isIntStr("123"))
sprint (isIntStr(123))
```

It works as expected with the following output:

```
isIntStr("123_dummy") : False
isIntStr("123") : True
isIntStr(123) : False
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this check?

Comment: Note, `isIntStr("          123          ")` is true here.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for highlighting, Yes, forgot to add: `isIntStr("          123          ") = True` is intended. bcoz later in the pipeline, this is converted to an int, which is the key for some dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution be better.

```
def is_int_or_str(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x.strip().isnumeric()
    else:
        return False

print(f"Check '123':    {is_int_or_str('123')}")
print(f"Check '  123  ':{is_int_or_str('   123   ')}")
print(f"Check '123abc': {is_int_or_str('123abc')}")
print(f'Check 123:      {is_int_or_str(123)}')
```

Output:

```
Check '123':    True

Check '   123   ': True

Check '123abc': False

Check 123:      False
```

If input like "½" or something should be False change .isnumeric() method on .isdigit()

Comment: `is_int_or_str("½")` -> True

Comment: Added new annotation about inputs like this. Thanks.

Comment: Whats wrong with "߂"? This is a number. And int("߂") -> 2. The task does not specify this is incorrect.

Comment: Also task need specify limitations of input. This will solve the problem of choosing a method.

Comment: @Andrew; no other limitations, as I posted: integer within quotes, integer, implying reasonable meaning of integer :)  hence cases like "1/2" or "mu" is not needed.  I tested your answer and this appears to be much faster, hence I will mark this as accepted, thanks; Yours: `4.75 µs ± 51.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` vs Mine: `149 µs ± 1.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `any()` function together with the `isDigit()` function as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859308/12373911