# How do I detect if a string with whitespace contains a number in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to seperate a list of mailing addresses and names that are intertwined in a single column due to poor formating. I initially wanted to grab all of the entries that are alphanumeric so I can separate them however I'm having trouble with the .isalnum() function. My string is a mailing address so I can't remove all of the white space as it would ruin the formatting.

```
'123 main st'.isalnum()
```

doesn't work because of the white space and I can't quite figure out how to effectively check if this is correct.

Comment: What's your data frame and expected output?

Comment: `'123 main st'.replace(' ', '').isalnum()` or using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Check if a string contains a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859282/check-if-a-string-contains-a-number).

```
def has_numbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

has_numbers("123 main st")
True
```